# How to restore the colour button in Ckeditor

Tags: civimail, 4.7, ckeditor

When I upgraded a site from 4.6 to 4.7 Ckeditor lost several buttons - Font, Size, Foreground Colour and Background Colour.  I figured out how to restore Font and Size but cannot see how to get the 2 colour buttons back.  I went to display preferences and set colorButtonbackStyle(Object) and  colorButtonforeStyle(Object) to true, saved and cleared caches, but no buttons showed up.  Am I wrong to use this GUI and so should I be updating a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to civicrm/admin/ckeditor?reset=1 you should be able to activate the plugin "Colorbutton".[image: CKEditor]

Comment: Thanks!  Worked but I had to clear browser, drupal and civi caches to see the update.  Thanks again.  Andy

Comment: I've added the plugin, but no buttons show in the colors menu group and I can't see how to add them

Comment: In case someone has the same problem like @MickKahn: You need to chose the plugin in the correct tab e.g. the CiviMail to have the button in the choices for CiviMail and clear the browser cache