# adding colour/color button to Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to add colour/color buttons to Ckeditor on a new site. I've done it on a previous site using configuration option for the editor in Administer >> Display preferences, but either I have forgotten something or something has changed with an upgrade.

As described in [How to restore the colour button in Ckeditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19562/how-to-restore-the-colour-button-in-ckeditor) I add the Colorbutton plugin, but no buttons appear. The color group was already there but it remains empty. I can't see any options for adding or moving individual buttons (just hiding buttons or adding separators).

I've tried clearing caches, but as it doesn't show in the config screen I don't think that is relevant.

CiviCRM 5.15.1 and WordPress 5.3.1

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache as was Civi cache?

Comment: cleared cache in CiviCRM, WordPress hosting and browser and no better. Didn't expect it to as the buttons do not show in the Ckeditor config panel.

Comment: I assume you are not seeing any errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke Stewart's suggestion in the comments above proved correct and its all fine in CiviCRM 5.26.2. I haven't marked his answer as correct though as the answer wasn't a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If clearing your browser cache and templates_c doesn't work. Try adding in both the Civimail and CiviEvents tabs - not just the default tab.

Comment: I added it to the default tab and it then shows as a plugin on the CiviMail an CiviEvent tabs without explicitly adding it so I can't add it again. It shows as a plugin but doesn't have any buttons.

Comment: Try removing it from the default tab - then add it individually on the CiviMail and CiviEvent tabs.

Comment: If you can't replicate here - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ - I'd recommend upgrading. There have been a couple of security releases since 5.15.1

Comment: removing from default and adding to CiviMail made no difference, But the WP demo site behave correctly so an upgrade is the next thing to try when I have a moment.

Comment: I'd definitely try some aggressive browser cache clearing as well.